# Extending a singleton class which has private constructor and destructor gives compile time warning

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, singleton, extend

I am using C++ (Qt).

I am extending a singleton class and a subclass has only static methods. 
I am not creating any instance of the SubClass. Singleton class has constructor and destructor are private, So I can not access its constructor and destructor.

```
 class Singleton 
 { 
   private :
           Singleton();
           ~Singleton();
   public :
      // some methods.
 }

 class SubClass : public Singleton
 {
   // There is NO constructor or destructor
   public:
   // Only some STATIC methods.
 }
```

I use the **SubClass::getInstance()** which calls getInstance() of parent.
I use only static methods of SubClass (so no need to instantiate the SubClass).

So my problem is, I am getting warning on compile -

"SubClass:destructor could not be generated because a base class destructor is inaccessible".

I want to get rid of these warnings and 
Also wanted to know that is this design violating singleton design pattern?

---

**What I want to Achieve?**

I am creating a logger for an application. I am using a logger class of third party library (QxtLogger of QxtCore library). This QxtLogger class is a singleton and has constructor and destructor private. I want a singleton class with all the methods that QxtLogger has and some additional static methods (which are specific to my application).

So I created a class which inherits the QxtLogger and added some static methods to it. What worries me is extending the singleton class which is generating the warnings (because base class constructor and destructor are not accessible).
So what should I do?

Comment: should the dtor of base class protected? as in 'protected: virtual ~Singleton();'

Comment: Why do you want to subclass the singleton when you are only adding static methods to the subclass? Your question apart, this scenario doesnt seem to make much sense. You do realize that the methods can be called using the sub-class directly without the need for an instance right?

Comment: @Raam I want the class which should have all the functions that the singleton have And some additional static methods. So I extended the singleton class. This can be achieved by writing a wrapper class over it. Which will end in writing lot of wrapper methods. And not supposed to be good idea.

Comment: @Anwar You may want to rephrase the question and add your limitations as well. As Luchian points out, your best bet is to use composition.

Comment: Are you inheriting to override virtual functions? If not, how do you intend to add any new functionality? If you are overriding virtuals, delegating to `Singleton::getInstance()` won't return a `SubClass` instance, and you won't have the new behaviour. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you have the problem which Singletons are imagined to solve?

Comment: @PeterWood What I want to achieve is a singleton class which is inherited from a singleton class(which is from third party library). I want a singleton class with some more static methods that this third party singleton class has. 

So I inherited the singleton class and added some static method to child class. Any other potential solution?

Comment: @Anwar Just let people use the original singleton. You're not adding anything to it. What do the additional static members do? They probably don't need to be on the singleton.

Answer (score 6):

You can't extend the class that has no visible constructors. And that was the intent of the class designer.

If they wanted the class to be extended, they'd have made the constructor/destructor `protected`.

I suggest you use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: I want the class which should have all the functions that the singleton have And some additional static methods. So I extended the singleton class. This can be achieved by writing a wrapper class over it. Which will end in writing lot of wrapper methods. And not supposed to be good idea.
Bottom line Code is working fine, but gives some warning.

Comment: @AnwarShaikh I already said you should use composition, even if that implies having wrapper methods. To me this sounds like the only correct solution, esp considering the constructor/destructor is marked as private - clear intent for the class not to be extended.

Comment: @AnwarShaikh or one other way is to not wrap the class at all, and just have some functions that operate on it.

Comment: @Griogre Class I am extending is a singleton, and all singletons have constructor and destructor private. Is that mean they are not supposed to extended?

Comment: @AnwarShaikh what do you mean you're extending a singleton? Wasn't that the problem, that you couldn't?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10874/discussion-between-anwar-shaikh-and-luchian-grigore)

Answer (score 2):

**STOP!**

Besides the dubious use (once again) of the Singleton anti-pattern, you should remember that C++ is not Java.

As a consequence, there are **better** ways that inheritance to extend the functionalities of a class: free-functions!

```
void extend1(Singleton& s, ...);

int extend2(Singleton const& s);
```

Note that those functions take a `Singleton` class by reference for 2 reasons:

- it becomes explicit that they depend on it
- it paves the road toward a refactoring, for when you'll get rid of the Singletonness